# Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../". in chrome

Tags: javascript

I've written a demo and I get two errors in Google Chrome, but no errors in Microsoft Edge.

An import map is added after module script load was triggered.

Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "three". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script async src="https://unpkg.com/es-module-shims@1.3.6/dist/es-module-shims.js"></script>
    <script type="importmap">
                  {
                    "imports": {
                      "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.144.0/build/three.module.js",
                      "three/addons/": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.144.0/examples/jsm/"
                    }
                  }
                </script>
</head>

<body>
    <script type="module">
        import * as THREE from 'three';
        import { OrbitControls } from 'three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js';
        // init
        const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 1000);
        camera.position.z = 1;
        // controls
        const scene = new THREE.Scene();
        const geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1, 1);
        const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();
        const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        scene.add(mesh);
        // texture
        const texture = new THREE.TextureLoader();

        const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        renderer.setAnimationLoop(animation);
        const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
        // animation
        function animation(time) {
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        }

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/foLkmt4z/

**Chrome**

[image]

**Edge**

[image]

What seems to be the problem in Google Chrome?

My Environment

- Windows 10
- Microsoft Edge version `105.0.1343.50`
- Google Chrome version `105.0.5195.127`

I've streamlined my code.

https://jsfiddle.net/s0h6w432/3/

the code in chrome  get two errors.

1.An import map is added after module script load was triggered.

2.Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "three". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

but edge get zero error.

I removed some chrome plugins. The error is gone.

Comment: Please post code, **error messages**, markup, data structures, and other textual information **as text**, not just as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: Your edit still leaves out half of the error messages you have in your screenshot.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, this import is not being handled by the [import map](https://github.com/WICG/import-maps):

```
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js';
```

I suspect the problem is that the `three/addons/` entry in the import map isn't being used for `three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js` (though it seems odd).

If so you can fix it by adding an entry for `three/addons/controls/`:

```html
<script type="importmap">
{
    "imports": {
        "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.144.0/build/three.module.js",
        "three/addons/": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.144.0/examples/jsm/",
        "three/addons/controls/": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.144.0/examples/jsm/controls/"
    }
}
</script>
```

---

That said, this error hidden in the screenshot is concerning:

> An import map is added after module script load was triggered.

This might be an issue with `es-module-shims`. You don't need that to use import maps on either Chrome 105 or Edge 105.

Comment: I've streamlined my code. I've remove controls and es-module-shims.  The error is still there.  and  I'm sorry I uploaded the image.